# Execution of python program for a fixed time

Tags: python-2.7

I am making a small computer game in python which is to run for 3 minutes. It is a console game. The screen doesn't update every few milliseconds but new information is printed out every few seconds and the player has to chose amongst different options.

So what I need is,

1. Ability to run a script before the 3 minute time
2. Ability to run a script for exactly 3 minutes.
3. The ability to know exactly how much time is remaining and how much is elapsed, while traversing the timed portion.
4. Ability to transfer control to another script to be run after the 3 minutes have elapsed.

Comment: Sounds like a project, do let us know how it goes.

Comment: It is not. Sincerely not. Had made the earlier game with fixed number of updates but that doesn't give the edgy-feel of the end game. Have to do a time based thing.

Comment: Do you really need separate Python programs ("script" as you seem to refer to one)?  Or can the whole system be a single Python program with Python functions, modules, etc. to subdivide the functionality?  If you can do it all in a single Python program, it will certainly be cleaner and easier than trying to manage run time of multiple Python programs.

Comment: Can do it. No issues there. I thought it might be simpler if it were different scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Well I figured it out eventually using threads and Locks.

```
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
from threading import Thread, Lock

locker = Lock()

def printsomething(string):
    if string.seconds:
        print string.seconds,"seconds left"
    else:
        print "less than a second left"

def func():
    start_time = datetime.now()
    while True:
        if locker.acquire(False):
            printsomething(timedelta(seconds=180) - (datetime.now()-start_time))
            raw_input("Continue? y/n")
            locker.release()
        else:
            print "Thread ending"
            return

t = Thread(target=func)
t.daemon = True

t.start()
t.join(180)
locker.acquire()
print "program ending"
```

The only thing that couldn't be solved was that the script/func that is supposed to run for 3 minutes doesn't exit as soon as the 3 minutes are over. Will update the answer if I figure it out.